# CSS Holy Grail layout

Tags: css

Can someone break down for me the pieces that compose the Holy Grail Layout with switched div positioning as seen here? http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

The way I understand is that:

- colmask is just a wrapper to position the content between header and footer
- colmid is another wrapper that i guess accomodates some browsers such as IE7
- colleft is the wrapper of the real thing (not sure why so many wrappers)
- col1, col2 and col3 are the real thing and are all floating left and set their margins to adjust their appearance on the screen

Can someone explain better what's the Zen of that design? I'm trying to apply it to a real world scenario and it's not really working.

Comment: Have you read: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/?

Comment: That one is using a different technique with negative margins, but i'll keep meditating about it to see if i can get a better understanding of the other holy grail i was referring to

Answer (score 4):

I came up with this layout after getting frustrated with all the suggestions out there. Its HTML5/CSS3 complient and works in IE8+ and atleast FF21 - I haven't tested in other versions and browsers. But if your looking for a fluid layout - this one works great.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
  <title>Canvas</title>
  <style type="text/css">

   * {padding:0px; margin:0px;}
   html, body {width:100%; height:100%;}

   #page {width:100%; height:100%;position:relative;}

     #page > #header {
         position:absolute;
         top:0px;
         left:0px;
         right:0px;
         height:64px;

         background:#ccc;
         }

     #page > #body {
         position:absolute;
         top:64px;
         left:0px;
         right:0px;
         bottom:64px;    
         }

       #page > #body > #left {
           position:absolute;
           top:0px;
           left:0px;
           bottom:0px;
           width:192px;  

           background:#bbb;
           }

       #page > #body > #center {
           position:absolute;
           top:0px;
           left:192px;
           right:192px;
           bottom:0px; 
           }

       #page > #body > #right {
           position:absolute;
           top:0px;
           right:0px;
           bottom:0px;
           width:192px; 
           background:#bbb; 
           }

     #page > #footer {
         position:absolute;
         bottom:0px;
         right:0px;
         left:0px;
         height:64px;
         background:#ccc;
         }

  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
   <div id="page">
     <div id="header"></div>
       <div id="body">
         <div id="left"></div>
         <div id="center"></div>
         <div id="right"></div>
       </div>
     <div id="footer"></div>
   </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The holy grail is a 3-column liquid layout where three columns are all the same length no matter how much content there is. T he columns should be in 2-3-1 order in the html(for SEO). The idea is to separate the content from the background color and place it into different divs. A floated container div will always be the height of it's floated contents, so what's going on here is for each content div, there is a matching relatively positioned floating container div. These are the three wrappers.

Step-by-step, it works like this:

1. Set up three columns nested inside of three nested wrappers.

   ```
   <div id="container-right">
     <div id="container-middle">
       <div id="container-left">
         <div id="col1">Column 1</div>
         <div id="col2">Column 2</div>
         <div id="col3">Column 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
   ```
2. Float em all and set their background colors(remember that col1 is the center!)
3. Set the wrapper widths to 100%. Set the col widths to something totaling 100% (40%, 30%, 30%). Make their positioning relative for both types.
4. Now all of the colored divs are on top of each other. Slide the column color wrapper divs over by setting the right property. Leave container-right alone. Move container-middle over 30% revealing the color beneath. Move container-left over more to reveal both.
5. Now the content is sitting off the left side of the viewport. Push each div into place with the same technique, but using the left property this time.
6. Finally, chop off the extra by setting overflow:hidden on the outermost wrapper. Please note you have to set the positioning to relative on the outer div or this step won't work in IE.