# CSS: Locking the boxes?

Tags: css

```
___________div class=MAIN_________________

div id=LEFT                   div id=RIGHT
__________________________________________
```

How can I achive that all the bottoms of the MAIN + LEFT + RIGHT box are glued together?

Basically locking the bottoms, say if there is a lot of contents in the LEFT box -> the RIGHT box will grow along with the LEFT and MAIN box.

__ follow up __

I don't know how to correctly implement into my code :(

http://jsfiddle.net/v572V/

I have copied the whole CSS file so it looks very messy. But the boxes are as follow

```
<div class="content home">
<div id="main">
<div id="sidebar">
```

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769171/css-holy-grail-layout

Comment: What's the lowest version of IE you're supporting. That makes a huge difference.

Comment: Other details that could help. Are any of the width's fixed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/teresko/EkTVv/

This is a variation on so-called "holy grail layout". Should work on all browsers, including IE6. The layout will expand to fit the longest of parts. If content is shorter then browser's height, then layout will extend to the height of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/DjQup/

you float the left and right columns in the container. then have an 'inner' content container with padding to offset the floats... see the example above.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="left">asd</div>
   <div class="right">asd</div>
   <div class="middle">
       <div class="middle-inner">
       asdf
       </div>
   </div>
</div>​


.container {
 height: 600px;
 widht: 800px;
 background-color: #aaa; 
 clear: both;    
}
.left, .right {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: blue;    
}
.left { float: left; }
.right { float: right; }
.middle {
 background-color: green;
 float: none;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.middle-inner {
 padding: 0 100px;   
}
​
```

it's not perfect but at least you can see the technique in play. gl.

Comment: teresko's answer is more complete.. I would review his CSS.. (much cleaner than mine)